# How to use waitUntilTableNotExists in DynamoDb describe table

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to delete and then create a DynamoDB table using nodejs aws sdk (version 3.142.0) and I wanted to use the waiters (waitUntilTableNotExists / waitUntilTableExists), but I don't understand how they are supposed to be used and I cannot find a good example online.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way after a createTable command in aws-sdk-js-v3 to wait for the table to complete. A note is that if you do NOT use `waitUntilTableExists` and instead attempt to use `DescribeTableCommand` it will incorrectly report TableStatus == 'ACTIVE' even though you cannot Read/Write to the table, you must use `waitUntilTableExists`.

```
import {
  CreateTableCommandInput,
  CreateTableCommandOutput,  
  waitUntilTableExists
} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "us-east-1" });


const data = await client.send(
      new CreateTableCommand({
        TableName: tableName,
        AttributeDefinitions: partitionAndSortKeyDefinitions,
        KeySchema: columnSchema,
        ProvisionedThroughput: {
          ReadCapacityUnits: 4,
          WriteCapacityUnits: 2,
        },
      })
);


// maxWaitTime - seconds
const results = await waitUntilTableExists({client: client, maxWaitTime: 120}, {TableName: tableName})
if (results.state == 'SUCCESS') {
  return results.reason.Table
}
console.error(`${results.state} ${results.reason}`);
```

Comment: One of the very few examples of how to use waitUntilTableExists to be found - but when I implement the above code I get a "message": "Internal Server Error" response.  This occurs when it tries to process the waitUntilTableExists function.

Comment: Finally resolved the issue I was having... waitUntilTableExists is an external wrapper around the DescribeTable command.   Therefore you have to make sure that you have permissions set within IAM that allows access to the Dynamo DescribeTable command!!